# How to send keys to input tag in python selenium in complicated element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Html Element:

```
<td style="">
<input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="" tabindex="6" class="text" onkeyup="setPriceLock(false); setOrder(); assignActPrice(this.value);" style="border: 1px solid rgb(207, 207, 207);">
</td>
```

Now I want to input a value into this input filed,I have tried many regular ways like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html//input[@id='price']").send_keys('333.95')
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('price').value = '333.95';")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#price").send_keys('333.95')
```

error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how you locate the element; it is not interactable.  The webpage is deliberately coded to not allow you to input anything into that element.  (Presumably there is some way to make it become interactable, perhaps by filling in some other field first.)

Comment: Have tried click first before send text?